# Extract elements from an array inside a jsonb field in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my Postgresql table, I have a jsonb field called `data`, which contains data in the following format:

```
{
 list:[1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I use the query:

```
select data->'list' from "Table" where id=1
```

This gives me the array `[1,2,3,4,5]`

The problem is that I want to use this result in another select query within the IN clause. It's not accepting the array.

`IN ([1,2,3,4,5])` fails

It wants:

`IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

So, In my original query I don't know how to covert [1,2,3,4,5] to just 1,2,3,4,5

My current query is:

```
select * from "Table2" where "items" in (select data->'list' from "Table" where id=1)
```

Please help

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you need to use the values in the list. Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query where you are trying to access the array's elements.

Comment: I updated the question and added my actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` to turn the elements into rows

```
select t2.*
from table_2 t2
where t2.items in (select jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.data -> 'list')::int
                   from table_1 t1 
                   where t1.id = 1);
```

This assumes that `items` is defined as `text` or `varchar` and contains a single value - however the name (plural!) seems to indicate yet another de-normalized column.

Comment: I think this is close but I still get error. I  created this demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=594f02927ae075f1c7ed8659c53fc341

Comment: @asanas: well, you are comparing an integer with a text value. You need to cast the result of the array. See my edit

Comment: @asanas Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: The query worked. Thanks a lot!. Yes, they are painful. I will avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array contains operator ([`@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)) rather than `IN` if you cast the search value to `jsonb`. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table2"
WHERE items::jsonb <@ (SELECT data->'list' FROM "Table" WHERE id=1)
```

Note that if `items` is an int you will need to cast it `char` before casting to `jsonb`:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table2"
WHERE cast(items as char)::jsonb <@ (SELECT data->'list' FROM "Table" WHERE id=1)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=55bd4d2c46c707ab8d70bc285b7ac7f3)